# Is it bad practice to use exceptions to assign variables?

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, variable-assignment

Is it bad practice to use the following to essentially do *"if dict and key exists, add an item to it, if it doesn't, create the dict and the key first and then add to it"*?

Additional question: Do I have to do `self.elements = {}` at instantiation for the first addition to it to work, or will it create it on the fly with the first `self.elements[elemType] = ...`?

It worked in the console but I'm sure I've had errors doing that before.

```
try:
    self.elements[elemType][elemObj.id] = elemObj
except KeyError as _:
    self.elements[elemType] = {elemObj.id:elemObj}
```

Comment: No that's fine, but wouldn't you typically create an empty dictionary at the beginning of the program as a placeholder?

Comment: I think that's fine, however you might want to consider using a `defaultdict` class to avoid altogether

Comment: Also, if you're not going to use the `Exception` instance, `except KeyError:` is fine.

Comment: The problem with this is you can end up catching and masking key errors you weren't expecting.

Comment: I don't think defaultdict would be appropriate, here.  The elements dictionary just receives elements from broadcast as they are added, they can be zwave nodes, android cameras, etc (this is a home security system) -- this dict is in my gui and is meant to catch elements added to the system by publisher broadcast and make buttons out of them to add to the gui.  I don't want it to know what types it can receive, just that it can receive them.  With a default dict I would have to define the keys and defaults, correct?

Comment: Eric -- wouldn't the extra key errors be thrown when the except block tries to assign it again?

Comment: jonrsharpe -- thanks, good catch

Comment: Malik - I could, it was just a "if I don't have to, I won't" type of thing.  I still haven't gotten used to python's "explicit is better than implicit" mantra

Answer (score 0):

Exception is always slow. You can assign values - by use dict update.

```
>>> foo = {1: {}}
>>> foo[1].update({1: 2})
>>> foo
{1: {1: 2}}
>>> foo[1].update({1: 3})
>>> foo
{1: {1: 3}}
>>> foo[1].update({2: 4})
>>> foo
{1: {1: 3, 2: 4}}
```

So in your case it look like

```
self.elements[elemType].update({elemObj.id: elemObj})
```

Or more complex if elements[elemType] may not exist

```
self.elements.update({elemType: {elemObj.id: elemObj} })
```

## upd

For not overwrite elemType - can check if it not exists.

```
if elemType not in self.elements:
    self.elements[elemType] = {}
self.elements[elemType].update({elemObj.id: elemObj})
```

Comment: Wouldn't update throw an error if elemType key wasn't already in the dictionary?  I don't want the dictionary to know what keys it might eventually have.

Comment: @ your edit: What happens if elemType already does exist and has information in it as this is the 20th item to be added of type "node", say, then it will overwrite everything in that key with a new definition, no?  Isn't the update only for elements, not the dictionary inside elements[elemType]?  This is getting confusing.

Comment: I thought it would come down to an if.  That's what I ended up with when I went down the update path and the minute I created the if, the pythonistas on SO started ringing in my head, "Python is not C, in Python EAFP > LBYL, Exceptions are cheap in Python, etc"

Answer (score 0):

Decided to check out what still works faster `if` or `try`.

## if.py

```
d = {}
for i in range(int(1e+6)):
    if i in d:
        d[i] += 1
    else:
        d[i] = 1
```

## try.py

```
d = {}
for i in range(int(1e+6)):
    try:
        d[i] += 1
    except KeyError:
        d[i] = 1
```

## result time for if

```
$ time python if.py 

real    0m0.269s
user    0m0.224s
sys     0m0.044s
```

## result time for try

```
$ time python try.py 

real    0m0.899s
user    0m0.858s
sys     0m0.040s
```

So `if` in three times faster than `try`.